# Override image tag if it is the first?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I am using TYPO3 7.6 with 'CSS Styled Content'.

What I want to do is override the img tag if it is the first image listed in the content element.

So I have added a custom img tag under `tt_content.image.20.1.1.layout.custom`

Now how do I override `tt_content.image.20.1.1.layoutKey` if it is the first image?

Eg:

```
tt_content.image.20.1.1.layoutKey.override = custom
tt_content.image.20.1.1.layoutKey.override.if {
    value = 1
    equals.field = imageOrderNumber??
}
```

Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a register containing the current image number: `register:IMAGE_NUM_CURRENT`.

So it should work like this:

```
tt_content.image.20.1.1.layoutKey.override = custom
tt_content.image.20.1.1.layoutKey.override.if {
    value = 1
    equals.data = register:IMAGE_NUM_CURRENT
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I just needed to change 1 to 0.

Comment: Oh, so the name is a bit confusing... Images are not counted (unlike as expected). The register takes simply the current index of the images array (which is starting with 0).